# How to remove a jar file from the external libraries directory, which is added by the gradle dependency, in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

First, I have added a dependency in gradle, and then sync the project. We have no error, but when we run the application, we got an error which is also showing in the image.

```
    :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/inject/Inject.class
```

We found a duplicate jar file with different version which is highlighted above. Now I want to remove only this duplicate jar file(`java.inject-1`).
Hope someone has a solution for this.

[image]

Comment: manually removing it is not the solution, next gradle sync it will be there again

Comment: yes, but i want to update gradle to exclude this file.

Comment: like this :- configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'javax.inject-1', module: 'org.igniterealtime:rest-api-client'
        all*.exclude module: 'java.inject'
    }    but this is also not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try below in your `gradle` dependency.

```
compile('org.igniterealtime:rest-api-client:1.1.3')
{exclude module: "javax.inject"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can close Android Studio, delete all the `.idea` folders and `.iml` files in your project and re-import.

Comment: Go to Project Structure > app> dependencies. at the right hand side you will see + and - select library which you want to delete and click on - button.

Comment: Hello pradeep my case is something different, please check my attached image http://i.stack.imgur.com/XJtjn.png

Comment: simply remove "compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')" form "dependencies" in my "build.gradle (Module: app) Try this sort of stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio Use **Refactor**. Just

> Right Click the .jar file choose "Refactor > safe delete"

.

Comment: safe delete is a disabled option for my case.