# Exclude jar file from library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have used this lib in my code

```
com.twilio:video-android:4.2.0
```

[image]

I want to exclude this jar file from it because it is conflicted with one other libraries

I have tried many ways but non of them work with me

Comment: just remove its reference from the build.gradle file

Comment: I do not have access to twilio gradle file to remove lib from it

Comment: please refer to this answer, It will solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538455/how-to-remove-a-jar-file-from-the-external-libraries-directory-which-is-added-b

Comment: Also a near self-repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657816/program-type-already-present-in-android-studio-when-using-twilio

Comment: found any solution on this?

Answer (score -1):

Use this to remove the library for one of the gradle dependency

```
implementation ('com.twilio:video-android:4.2.0'){
    exclude module:'<whatever module is in libwebrtc.jar>'
}
```

Comment: I use all these combination and not work implementation ('com.twilio:video-android:4.2.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.webrtc'
        exclude module: "org.webrtc"
        exclude module: "libwebrtc"
        exclude module: "libwebrtc.jar"
        exclude module: 'libwebrtc'
        exclude module: 'libwebrtc.jar'
    }

Answer (score -1):

please try below in your gradle dependency.

```
implementation ('com.twilio:video-android:4.2.0'){
    exclude module: "libwebrtc.jar"
}
```

Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538455/how-to-remove-a-jar-file-from-the-external-libraries-directory-which-is-added-b) for further help.

Comment: I use all these combination and not work implementation ('com.twilio:video-android:4.2.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.webrtc'
        exclude module: "org.webrtc"
        exclude module: "libwebrtc"
        exclude module: "libwebrtc.jar"
        exclude module: 'libwebrtc'
        exclude module: 'libwebrtc.jar'
    }

Comment: please try this one
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20073207/5701085
I hope it should work, if it works, let me know I'll modify my answer, For jar we'll use exclude group, instead of excluded module.